# Drivers Certification for Microsoft with HLK and VHLK

Tags: microsoft-partner-center, hlk

Good afternoon. I am doing the certification process for a driver with Microsoft, but to do so you must pass the HLK tests.

After doing the entire Client - Server process, installing HLK client, loading the driver into the tool and running the tests, when creating the .hlkx package and uploading it to the Microsoft partner site I get an error "The file you selected is not a valid format for submission. Verify your selection and, if needed, recreate your submission package and try again."

I have not been able to continue with the process even though I have the EV certificate and other requirements requested by Microsoft.

I followed this tutorial as is https://subcom.notion.site/Getting-your-minifilter-signed-from-Microsoft-8845ed55ca6346fcb7f708a57e9ce726#fec6b5bb8aa6494a9e098f4b9e8b112a

and I have searched in the direct Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/

but in none of them does it give me a light that I may be missing